# Saving Location for next form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Alright so I'm doing something with next buttons that open new forms, annoying thing is that new forms pop up somewhere I don't want to on the desktop.

I'm trying to get the new form to spawn on the location of the old form with the code below, unfortunately for whatever reason it's not working at all, they still pop up the same way as before. And yes I have registered the events.

Form1:

```
System.Drawing.Point LocationPoint = new System.Drawing.Point(200,200);
private void Installer_template_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save the window location to the installer arts
    LocationPoint = this.Location;
}
private void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var NextForm = new Form2(LocationPoint);
    NextForm.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Form2

```
  public Form2(System.Drawing.Point LocationPoint)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Location = LocationPoint;
    }
```

The code is something along those lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [StartPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) of the new forms, i.e.

```
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

or

```
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty I fixed it, it was a bunch of problems.

1. Wrong property, gotta use DesktopLocation instead of Location property
2. Second I had some issues with static member that couldn't be modified or whatever the error is, I just used the settings file to save my location instead
3. Having that done, it still didn't work because you can't just do this.DesktopLocation = something, you have to use this.SetDesktopLocation(X, Y)
4. Still didn't work, because it got overwritten by other code when loading the form so you had to use the Shown even of the form and run it in there..